# Why is wcsncpy_s not working under linux Environment

Tags: c++, linux, string, windows, cross-platform

I tried creating a program by getting the latest standards and library. Below is the minimum reproducible code for the same. I have created this code by taking reference from- https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcsncpy

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main()
{
    wchar_t a[5];
    wcsncpy_s(a, 5, L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 9);
}
```

Now, for the windows, it works fine but for linux, this throws an error which says that:-

```
 error: use of undeclared identifier 'wcsncpy_s'
 wcsncpy_s(a, 5, L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 9);
```

Can anybody could explain, if there is a problem with the library included or with the function itself?

Comment: First of all these "secure" functions are part of the C specification, not C++. Secondly, the "secure" functions was added as a nod to Microsoft, but the Microsoft implementations still differ from the official C specification. Unless you specifically target Windows I recommend you avoid those functions.

Comment: your link is to some C documentation. C != C++